# Single Character input in c language in ubuntu

Tags: c

I just came across this:

```
#include <stdio. h>

int main() 
{
 char fname,sname;
 printf("your first name?: ");
 flushall();
 scanf("%c", &fname);
 printf("your last name?: "); 
 scanf("%c", &sname);
 printf("initials: %c.   %c",fname,sname);

return 0;
}
```

Problem is I'm getting printf statements and m unable to input anything.

It just skips the input part...

P.S.: I'm using ubuntu 15.10 and used `fflush(stdin)` and `fpurge()` but none of them worked.

Comment: Your code is both erroneous and incomplete.  Present a [mcve] if you want commentary about program behavior.  Also present sample input, expected output, and actual output to clarify your confusion about the program's behavior.

Comment: *"i came across this."* Where did you find it?

Comment: So if you enter 2 keystrokes:<A> and <Enter>, `'A'` goes into `fname` and `'\n'` goes into `sname`.  Did it work that way for you?

Comment: Hm you could try it the other way round from @chux: <Enter> and then <A> (followed by <Enter> of course). If you change the `printf` output format specifiers to `%d` you might get a clearer idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

First, include `stdio_ext.h` to use `__fpurge()`;

Before every `scanf()`, do a `_fpurge(stdin)`.

It worked fine for me.

You give no informantion on **how** you used `__fpurge()`. This is why I'm giving you an answer telling you to try `__fpurge()` again. x)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>
int main() 
{
 char fname,sname;
 printf("your first name?: ");
 __fpurge(stdin);
 scanf("%c", &fname);
 printf("your last name?: "); 
 __fpurge(stdin);
 scanf("%c", &sname);
 printf("initials: %c.   %c",fname,sname);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works well.I think, after the second scanf extra space needed for other characters(like newline ie)
Second scanf should be like this->> `scanf(" %c",&sname)`
And `flushall` not necessery i think

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
 char fname,sname;
 printf("your first name?: ");
 scanf("%c", &fname);
 printf("your last name?: "); 
 scanf(" %c", &sname);
 printf("initials: %c.   %c",fname,sname);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a pity you did not see the earlier, similar, answer which was deleted after the reply *"generally pointing out mistakes is an appropriate use of comments if you cannot be certain whether such responses actually answer the question."*